# Swift - CGPoint is not convertible to Character

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, cgpoint

I'm getting the following error:
[image]

When I print "location" I can clearly see it is a CGPoint.  I want to move the position of one my sprites based on the location.  In this example, I want to move the sprite to the left if the user touches the left half of the screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `<` operator defined for `CGPoint`, so I think that's the reason why you see that misleading compilation error. If you want to check the condition "left half of the screen touched" you probably have to change that line to:

```
if location.x < self.frame.size.width * 0.5 {
```

Comment: Yes!  I knew it was something fairly straightforward.  Still new to Obj-C & Swift, so a big thank you for your simple answer.